# C# product catalog

Tags: c#, xml, store

I want to create a product catalog in C# windowforms desktop app I want to add a search tool in which it will search from various stores that I choose. the stores to search from are amazon, ebay, dell, apple and sites similar. now is there a smart and effective way of getting data from each store and displaying it on the form in one format i.e.: product name, picture, price, store. I know that amazon has the product api while I'm unsure if dell has something like that along with other online stores. I do not want to have to code separate data templates for each store, but if I have to then I have to :/ any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: er, yes: you need to talk to each separate API using that API's protocol and definitions; there's no magic bullet here

Comment: yea i was afraid you'd say that.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to develop this from scratch - there's nothing ready-built, as far as I know.